# Firebase. LimitToFirst is not working but LimitToLast is working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am Writing a code to bring data of water from yesterday. but when I write LimitToLast its working perfectly but the data i am getting is not right so I write LimitToFirst instead of LimitToLast but after writing LimitToFirst my code start giving error in console.

```
cloudDb.collection(...).where(...).where(...).orderBy(...).limitToFirst is not a function
```

I have write the code like this

```js
var water1 = 0;
  cloudDb.collection('AKVO_RND').where("machine_id", "==", localStorage.getItem('machineid')).where("date", "<=", date_yesterday).orderBy("date").limitToFirst(1).get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
      water1 = doc.data().water;

    });
  })
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the reference documentation for the [`Query` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query) you'll find that there is no `limitToFirst` method - it only has `limit` and `limitToLast`. You'll want to use `limit(1)` in your code.

Comment: @Puffelen I have write this code for getting Yesterday 1st data but after writing `limit(1)` I am getting data of 10th May am I doing something wrong Please check my code here https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-lehmann-tdstyf

Comment: That sounds like the original problem is fixed and you now have a new problem @MOHAMMADZEESHAN, so I recommend opening a new question for it with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *inside* the question itself.